# How to convert optional pointer argument from C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, c++, reference, arguments

I have function in c++ something like this:

```cpp
// C++
bool Foo(int* retVal = NULL)
{
    // ...
    if (retVal != NULL)
        *retVal = 5;
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

And I can use functions in two ways:

```cpp
int ret;
Foo(&ret);

Foo();
```

When I write code in C# I used ref keyword:

```cs
// C#
bool Foo(ref int retVal = null)
{
    // ...
    if (retVal != null)
    {
        retVal = 5;
    }
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

but compiler said:

***A ref or out parameter cannot have a default value.***

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could use a nullable type like `int?`.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: @NathanOliver Note that while this will work for `ref int`, for parameters like `ref string` this doesn't work

Comment: @xanatos aren't strings nullable by default in c# so you wouldn't need to use `?`?

Comment: @NathanOliver That in no way solves the problem that `ref` parameters cannot have default values.

Comment: @NathanOliver But then you can't distinguish between the passing of a `ref null string` and "I don't want to pass a `string`"... In C it would be `char** str`. You could have `str == NULL`  or `*str == NULL`

Comment: @xanatos As the provided error message indicates, you can't use default parameter values on `ref` fields anyway, so that's irrelevant as such a program wouldn't even compile in the first place.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want to check for null? If you are trying to provide an overloaded function, then do just that - declare two functions, one with and one without a parameter. If you are trying to protect yourself against the user enetering a null reference, then you don't really need to provide a default value for the ref parameter, the subsequent check is enough.

Comment: Is this for native interop?

Comment: You could simply return a composite object, `Tuple<bool, int>` if you're lazy, a custom type if you're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simplest* way would be to just write an overload:

```
bool Foo()
{
    int notUsed;
    return Foo(ref notUsed);
}

bool Foo(ref int retVal)
{
    // ...
    retVal = 5;
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

If you actually need to know whether the `ref` value is needed, well, you can still use pointers, but you'll need an `unsafe` context:

```
unsafe bool Foo()
{
    return Foo(null);
}

unsafe bool Foo(ref int retVal)
{
    return Foo(&retVal);
}

private unsafe bool Foo(int* retVal)
{
    // ...
    if (retVal != null)
    {
        *retVal = 5;
    }
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Or, without `unsafe` as suggested in the comments, as pointers in C# may be considered as *heavy artillery*:

```
bool Foo()
{
    var notNeeded = 0;
    return Foo(ref notNeeded, false);
}

bool Foo(ref int retVal)
{
    return Foo(ref retVal, true);
}

private bool Foo(ref int retVal, bool retValNeeded)
{
    // ...
    if (retValNeeded)
    {
        retVal = 5;
    }
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing (my first revision was the same http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31075073/1). But then I noticed that we are losing information here... The C version can distinguish if `retVal*` was passed or not, and perhaps do some heavy calculation to return it, while the C# can't do it... The C# version is purely syntactic sugar to make the method easier to call.

Comment: @xanatos yes, I noticed that `if` in the original code... I'll write a second way.

Comment: Unsafe code... Please don't do that... Think about the children! :-) If you really want, you could pass an array of one element... Or better simply an additional `bool` parameter. You are already shielding the "real" method with two methods... Add to the real method a `bool`.

Comment: I'd rather add another `bool fillOutput` parameter on an internal method which the two public overloads set appropriately.

Comment: OK, I've added the `bool` way as suggested, but my stance is that children shouldn't be shielded from pointers at all costs :-P

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In this case it wasn't "child programmers", it was one of the keywords that win arguments like "think of the children", "terrorists", "even nazis did it"... :-)

Comment: @xanatos yes, I understood that this way - hey, I didn't write `goto` after all :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You get a point for reminding me about the unsafe keyword :D. However hinally, I modify the function, and use nullable int.

Answer (score 3):

The `ref` of C# is more similar to the `&` (reference) of C++ than to the `*` of C and C++ (pointer). As C++ references, they must reference something.

Now, you could:

```
public class OptionalRef<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator OptionalRef<T>(T value)
    {
        return new OptionalRef<T> { Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator T(OptionalRef<T> optional)
    {
        return optional.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value != null ? Value.ToString() : null;
    }
}
```

then

```
static bool Foo(OptionalRef<int> retVal = null)
{
    // ...
    if (retVal != null)
    {
        retVal.Value = 5;
    }
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

and you use it like:

```
Foo(); // null passed
Foo(null); // same

Foo(5); // not interested if the value is changed

// Full use
OptionalRef<int> val = 5;
Foo(val);
int ret = val;
```

**note that I'm not fully endorsing the semantics I wrote**

It is more a case of *you asked for something, I gave you something, no questions asked*

Comment: I like your disclaimer.  Can you elaborate on what you think about this a little more?  You don't have to put it in your answer, but is there a better way you'd do this, or do you like the ref solution?

Comment: @think I fully support Lucas patterns, excluding the unsafe one. BUT I do feel that they are all more or less hacks. I like a little more mine, but we are still speaking of choosing one vegetable instead of another. There is no fish or meat to be seen at this table.

Comment: @think it is important to comprehend that not everything that can be easily done in C can be easily done in C#. Good C patterns aren't always good C# patterns. So we have to comprehend, accept and carry on, and not try to emulate every nook and cranny of C

Comment: @xantos thanks that emulates how I feel.  I've been working on a C++ to C# application and we aren't doing enough "rethinking" at this stage.  Not to say that won't come later, but it's a lot of C++ fit to C# not C++ redesigned to C#.  The accuracy requirement of this application makes it so that makes sense for us though on our timeline.

Comment: I love your comment "Think about the children!". I like your solution with OptionalRef<T> class, but I was looking for simpler solution like unsafe :P.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about this one of two ways.  If you REALLY want to have a reference to your object you can wrap that in a class.  Those are always passed by reference so you'll get your modification the way you want and you can instantiate it to null.

Here is an example.

```
public class HolderObject
{
    public string myStr {get; set;}
}
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {    
        var xyz = new HolderObject() {
            myStr = "1234"
        };
        Console.WriteLine(xyz.myStr);
        FixString(xyz);
        Console.WriteLine(xyz.myStr);
        FixString();
        Console.WriteLine(xyz.myStr);


    }

    private static bool FixString(HolderObject input = null)
    {
        if (input != null)
            input.myStr = "test";
        return true;
    }
}
```

prints

```
1234
test
```

Another solution is to overload your function.

```
bool Foo()
{        
    // ...
    return true;
}

bool Foo(ref int retVal = null)
{
    // ...
    if (retVal != null)
    {
        retVal = 5;
    }
    return Foo();
}
```

I REALLY don't like this.  I'm actually in the middle of working on code in C# that has been pulled directly from C++.  Functions that are nested 6 or 7 layers deep modifying an object that was passed by reference.  That is hard to read and if you look at the code analysis warnings, it will suggest you don't use ref values.

If you can I'd move away from passing by ref as much as possible and return the value back that has been modified.  Or pass an object back that contains both your bool and your new value.